# No matter what i type in for username is successful?

Tags: php, html

I have the following PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$name = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if (!$con) {
    die('Connection Failed' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("login", $con);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE data SET password ='$password' WHERE username='$name'");

if (!$result) {
    echo "FAIL";
} else {
    echo "Update successfully";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the HTML file:

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="Edit.php">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br><br>
    <label>PasswordL</label>
    <input type="password:" name="password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="edit">
</form>
```

No matter what I type in for the username, it prints that the update succeeded.

How can I get it to check if the username does not exist within the database? Is there something wrong with my PHP code?

Comment: The query won't fail, it simply won't find any records to update, which is still a valid result in SQL

Comment: Now please stop using mysql_*: switch to using mysqli or pdo, with prepared statements/bind variables, and avoid opening up your code to SQL Injection

Comment: ok. Thanks for advising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not getting an error is because it is not an error to ask the database to update records on certain conditions and resulting in no records being updated.  It would only be an error if there was a syntax error.

With your current code, you could use `mysql_affected_rows()` to check if any row was updated.

Note that the Mysql library you use is deprecated and insecure.  You should instead use prepared statement using PDO or mysqli drivers instead.

Comment: My pleasure.  Can you now accept my answer to close your question?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something wrong with my PHP code?

1. **Yes**, Your `mysql_query` will **always** return `true` **even** if doesn't find any records to update. To check if any rows were affected using `PDO` use `rowCount()`.
2. `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security
   issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`
   extensions. Here's a `PDO` example:

---

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["username"])  and  isset($_POST["password"])){

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //construct the sql query. I'm not sure if password is a reserved mysql keyword, be careful with that. 
    //http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html
    $sql = "UPDATE data SET password = :password WHERE username = :name ";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    //bind the post parameters to $sql
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $_POST["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST["username"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // check  if rowCount() returns 1 or more affected rows.
    if($stmt->rowCount()){
        echo "UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY";
    }else{
        echo "NOT UPDATED";
    }
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;

}else{
    echo "Form is incomplete!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have another select statement after the update to check if the record exists with the username and password. And as the others have said, start using PDO and hash your password (if you are not doing this already). You are wide open to sql injection hacks.

```
SELECT 1 FROM db.table WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ? Limit 1
```

Reference: [Check if record exists delete it using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728133/check-if-record-exists-delete-it-using-mysql)